# Как отобразить прогресс выполнения загрузки содержимого JSON файла?

Tags: java, android, json, progress-bar, android-asynctask

Есть **AsyncTask**, который загружает по URL json файл с сервера и раскидывает его содержимое в **ArrayList**. Хотелось бы вывести прогресс выполнения этой самой загрузки. Ибо файл весит около 300кбайт, и не всегда загрузка выполняется быстро. Нужно как-то информировать, сколько уже скачалось и осталось.

```
public static class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>{

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    Integer result = 0;
    try  {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Station>>() {}.getType();
        List<Station> chunk = null;
        String baseUrl = "http://mysite.ru/json/default.json";
        try {
            stations = new ArrayList<>();
            chunk = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(new URL(baseUrl).openStream(),"UTF-8"), listType);
            stations.addAll(chunk);
            Station.sort(stations);
            indexStations(stations);
            result = 1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "error loading station: %s", e);


          result = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
        if (result == 1) {
            ...
        }
        if (result == 0) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Сейчас вывожу простой **ProgressDialog**, в котором прогресс-бар вертится бесконечно, и закрываю его, если `result` станет равным **1** в методе `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

Ответ прост, но для вашего кода затруднителен). Всё что вам необходимо сделать это создать итерацию, по вашему усмотрению.
Если это размер, то можно поделить его на 100 `(size/100) = chunk`, и при выполнении записи каждого итерировать и ваш прогресс. У вас AsyncTask, у него между потоками есть специальный инструмент и это действительно довольно легко сделать. Вот пример думаю быстро разберетесь, просто придумайте шаг итерации от чего отталкиваться, дальше всё уже есть.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```